# What is the most likely used method to check whether a given date lies in the list of a date range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, date

Objective:
To find the value associated with the date range.
Date is stored in `YYYYMMDD` format and no two date ranges will overlap each other.

```
Sample Data:
20160201 - 20160227 = 100
20160301 - 20160320 = 101
20160321 - 20160331 = 102
```

To avoid the linear search, I stored the above date range in STL as follows,

```
std::map< DateRangePair<int,int>, int> l_date_range_value_map;
```

And did operator overloading for less than symbol

```
/* DateRangePair implementation */
template<typename T1,typename T2>
class DateRangePair
{
   public:
      T1 key1;
      T2 key2;

      DateRangePair(T1 a,T2 b): key1(a),key2(b) {}

      bool operator<(const DateRangePair<T1,T2> &obj)const
      {
         return (key1 < obj.key1 && key2 < obj.key2);
      }

};
```

I assume this will find the value associated with the date range in binary search(or some other efficient search, depends on implementation) rather than linear search.

Can this be implemented in any other model with a decreased space or time complexity?

Comment: Why the linear search is not an option for you?

Comment: @werediver: Because it's terrible and unnecessary?

Comment: Premature optimisation is terrible and unnecessary. If you don't experience any performance issues, you should not increase your code complexity.

Comment: @werediver: That's a ridiculous generalisation. There are very few occasions in which a linear search is acceptable, and alternatives are basically trivial to implement. For example, by using a `std::map`, which organises its elements into a tree "ordered" by key, inherently giving you better than a linear search... which the OP is already using. You'd actually have to do _more_ work to make an effective linear search. Why would you do that? "Prematurely optimising loops" or "prematurely hand-crafting assembly" is not the same as "writing sensible code".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Less work should win if you have no significant resources penalty. If you can achieve better results by just using an appropriate container, that's not a question.

Comment: @werediver: In this case, the proper way _is_ less work, as I've said. You'd have to do _more work_ to make this a linear search. You'll find that if you use standard containers as designed, you get the best results for the least effort. It's not until you try fighting against them that things get hard. In general, you'd have to have designed your program wrong, or be using the wrong container, to get into a situation where a linear search is actually desirable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then I agree with you :) (but that all that doesn't conflicts with my second comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to really improve on time or space complexity in this problem. std::map is implemented as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which has time complexity of O(log n) for insert and search operations, and space complexity of O(n). Is this part of your project really a bottleneck?

If std::map finds are bottlenecking your program, I would suggest using binary search over a sorted vector for a problem like this, using something like [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or a simple home-cooked function. While this approach would have the same theoretical upper-bounds on time and space-complexity, it would most likely have slightly less overhead and a slightly faster runtime.

Additionally, is there a reason why key1 and key2 can take on different types? I can't see any scenario where having two  types for yyyymmdd format would be beneficial. If they're just in yyyymmdd format, a 32-bit integer would cover all possible dates, unless the class templates are required by something else in your project.

Comment: Some times  i will using the yyyymmddhhmmss format. When i want like that format then i will go for unsigned int

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard library will use something better than a linear search if it can, and here it can because your comparator is not only used for searching but also for arranging the data into a tree.

That means *it's already in a form efficient for searching*, and you're using `std::map` as it was designed to be used.

If you want something better you'll have to more strongly define your requirements and show your profiling results. But, realistically, I see no obvious way or reason to improve upon this.